# Manipulating the list of data from stored procedure to be used in another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently I'm writing a stored procedureusing T-SQL in SQL Server. My script contains code to run another stored procedure to get list of data from a table. I want to manipulate the data, using the list of data to modify them for another purpose (e.g. summing up a column and adding more lists of data) from the stored procedure. A way that I know is to create a temporary table. But after that, I'm not so sure. Please help. thanks.

This is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AJU_Rpt_ARAgingSp]
    (@Slsman_Starting slsmantype = NULL,
     @Slsman_Ending slsmantype = NULL,
     @Custnum_Starting custnumtype = NULL,
     @Custnum_Ending custnumtype = NULL,
     @CustType endusertypetype = NULL,
     @CutOff_Date datetype = NULL,
     @SumToCorp ListYesNoType = NULL, -- >> 0 = individual, 1 = corp customer
     @ShowActive ListYesNoType = NULL, -- >> 0 = all trx, 1 = active only
     @TransDomCurr ListYesNoType = NULL, -- >> 0 = dont convert, 1 = convert to local currency
     @AgingBasis ArAgeByType = NULL, -->> i = invoice date, d = due date
     @LeftToRight ListYesNoType = NULL, -- >> 0 = right to left, 1 = left to right
     @CurrSite NVARCHAR(8),
     @ShowDetailInfo NVARCHAR(1) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF ISNULL(@CurrSite ,'') = '' 
       SET @CurrSite = (SELECT TOP 1 site_ref FROM parms_mst)

    DECLARE @v_StartDate DateType

    SET @Slsman_Starting = ISNULL(@Slsman_Starting, dbo.LowCharacter())
    SET @Slsman_Ending = ISNULL(@Slsman_Ending, dbo.HighCharacter())
    SET @Custnum_Starting = ISNULL(@Custnum_Starting, dbo.LowCharacter())
    SET @Custnum_Ending = ISNULL(@Custnum_Ending, dbo.HighCharacter())
    SET @v_StartDate = dbo.LowDate()
    SET @CutOff_Date = GETDATE()

    EXEC dbo.ApplyDateOffsetSp @v_StartDate OUT, NULL, 0

    EXEC AJU_Rpt_DebtorSp
         @CustNumStart          = @Custnum_Starting
        ,@CustNumEnd            = @Custnum_Ending
        ,@DistDateStart         = @v_StartDate
        ,@DistDateEnd           = @CutOff_Date
        ,@CurrCodeStart         = NULL
        ,@CurrCodeEnd           = NULL
        ,@SlsmanStart           = @Slsman_Starting
        ,@SlsmanEnd             = @Slsman_Ending
        ,@TerritoryStart        = NULL
        ,@TerritoryEnd          = NULL
        ,@CustTypeStart         = NULL
        ,@CustTypeEnd           = NULL
        ,@SiteGroup             = @CurrSite
        ,@ConsolidatePayment    = NULL
        ,@DisplayResult         = 1

END
```

Comment: Create a temporary table that matches the result set returned by the proc. Then load the table using `INSERT INTO #temptable EXEC AJU_Rpt_DebtorSp …`.

Comment: Have you looked at table value variables?

Answer (score 0):

Since the initial result table is temporarily needed, you could do as follows:

1. In the invoking procedure, create a table variable with identical structure as returned by the invoked procedure,
2. Write within the invoking procedure a statement like the following:

   ```
   INSERT INTO @_Tempo_Table
       EXEC Invoked_Procedure (<params>) ;
   ```
3. Within the invoked procedure issue a `SELECT` that will return the records set.

If, in the other hand, you need to pass the initial table to the invoked procedure:

1. Create a type with a structure identical to the table that needs to be shared,
2. Add to the invoked procedure an argument of the type you just created (must be declared as `READONLY`),
3. Once you have the table with data within the invoking procedure, make the call to the invoked procedure passing the table variable as argument.

This methods will render the best performance (here I'm assuming that you are not passing a table with millions of records; if you do, it will still be the fastest way though you might need a lot of memory).